# Trim redundant attributes in json objects using java

Tags: java, mongodb, json

I would like to trim the below json object. That is a json object I built on top of what mongoDB responded. What I want to do is to remove just $oid because they are redundant attributes and keep the value inside (_id or $id ) without Curley braces and simply call the attribute id. 
so what I need is just "id": "2283cef627ff2cc33ad5990" 
Could you please help me I am struggling with json.

```
{
   "_id": {
       "$oid": "22383cef627ff2cc33ad5990"
   },

  "name": "data1",

  "users": [
   {
      "$ref": "user",
      "$id": {
          "$oid": "16a5fbcee4b0c2c2da3017ef"
      }
   },
   {
      "$ref": "user",
      "$id": {
          "$oid": "1795ff86e4b09fc66416cd2f"
       }
   },
 ],
},
```

Answer (score 0):

a) You can use a mapper to convert your JSON to an object and then call the desired attribute, like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = YOUR_STRING;

//from String to MyClass
MyClass object = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, MyClass.class);
```

In this example you have to define a class MyClass with all the attributes you need (e.g. _id, name, users, etc).

b) If you want to implement a quicker solution you can manipulate directly the string; if you know that the oid is always 24 characters you can do something like

```
String c = str.substring(str.indexOf("\"", str.indexOf("$oid")+6)+1, str.indexOf("\"", str.indexOf("$oid")+6)+25);
```

but I highly recommend to take a look to Jackson and give it a try. A solution like this is very fragile and every change in the JSON will lead to a wrong result.